# Passing WebAsembly memory to WebGL2

Tags: javascript, webassembly, webgl2

In WebGL2, there are additional versions of most existing functions that accept `ArrayBuffer`s that allow passing in offset and length inside these buffers. Supposedly, this should make it easier to pass in data from WebAssembly memory without creating temporary views, but there's a catch: those functions only accept `ArrayBufferView`.

1. What is the reason for such limitation? Why should a function that copies bytes to GPU care about their semantics, i.e. Uint8/Int32/Float32, etc?
2. How to get around it, without creating a `DataView` every time (which would completely defeat the purpose of using those functions in the first place)? Creating DataView once wouldn't work because WebAssembly memory can re-allocate its buffer, and there is no way to set a callback for memory resize.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why `texImage2D` etc take an ArrayBufferView and not just an ArrayBuffer as well. I agree it seems pointless.

At worst you should be able to only create a new view when the buffer changes.

Example:

```
;; hello.wat
(module
  ;; Import our trace function so that we can call it in main
  (import "env" "trace" (func $trace (param i32)))
  ;; Define our initial memory with a single page (64KiB).
  (memory $0 1)
  ;; Store a null terminated string at byte offset 0. 
  (data (i32.const 0) "Hello world!\00")
  ;; Export the memory so it can be read in the host environment.
  (export "memory" (memory $0))
  (func $alloc (param $0 i32) (result i32)
    get_local $0
    grow_memory
  )
  (export "alloc" (func $alloc))
  ;; Define the main function with no parameters.
  (func $main
    ;; Call the trace function with the constant value 0.
    (call $trace (i32.const 0))
  )
  ;; Export the main function so that the host can call it.
  (export "main" (func $main))
)
```

and the js that calls it

```
// hello.js
async function doit() {
  const response = await fetch('../out/main.wasm');
  const buffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
  const module = await WebAssembly.compile(buffer);
  const instance = await WebAssembly.instantiate(module, {
    env: {
      trace
    }
  });

  let exports = instance.exports;

  let view = new Uint8Array(exports.memory.buffer);
  function getView() {
    if (view.buffer !== exports.memory.buffer) {
      console.log('new view');
      view = new Uint8Array(exports.memory.buffer);
    }
    return view;
  }

  function trace(byteOffset) {
    let s = '';
    const view = getView();
    for (let i = byteOffset; view[i]; i++) {
      s += String.fromCharCode(view[i]);
    }
    console.log(s);
  }

  exports.main();
  exports.main();
  exports.main();
  exports.alloc(10);
  exports.main();
  exports.main();
  exports.main();
}

doit().then(() => {
  console.log("done");
});
```

The only time a new view is created is when WebAssembly reallocates the buffer

Since apparently you need a different type of view depending on the `type` parameter passed to WebGL2 you'll need a set of views instead of just one view and based on the type parameter you need to get the correct type of view.

Copied from the comments:

1. texImage2D and bufferData etc are not generally functions that are called in a tight loop so optimizing them past the point above doesn't seem like that big a deal? The check is simple and not likely to affect performance and GC is avoided
2. I did't find any way to get a callback when `grow_memory` is called. On the other hand if you're writing your own webassembly you can easily have all your `grow_memory` calls go through your own function and have that function call into JavaScript to update your views. I'm guessing this is what emscripten does. It has a runtime library. I assume that runtime library gets called when they want to grow memory and so they can update their views.

Comment: First of all, [this is not true](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ArrayBufferView) (and all WebGL functions that expect a view accept it); second, it does not answer either of my questions.

Comment: I would've done that, but I don't like the extra overhead in every function call. It's not nearly as bad as poking garbage collector, but ideally I'd love to (1) find out why the limitation exists in the first place (why can't the function accept arraybuffer), and (2) somehow place a hook on memory realloc - it could be done by manually calling handler from wasm, but not so easy if the code is generated by emscripten. I don't suppose hooking into `Memory.grow` function would work?

Comment: Hmm, I tried hooking into `Memory.grow` but my hook wasn't called. I'd go raise the issue on the [WebGL github issues](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/WebGL/issues) or the [public webgl mailing list](https://www.khronos.org/webgl/public-mailing-list/).

Comment: I really hate mailing lists, but I'll try github, thanks.

Comment: Another suggestion would be to [dig through the emscripten code](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/9a07fdfce7eabcf43fb341bf0c6741f3875544bc/src/library_gl.js#L1383) and see what they are doing. Just guessing they don't have to rely on `grow` since they're running C they can just have their version of `malloc` call out to some `update the views` function when it calls `grow`.

Comment: One other question is "why does it matter?". No apps I know of call texImage2D 1000s of times a frame. The solution above has no GC so the fact that it's only going to go through that code at most a few times a frame (zero times for the majority of WebGL apps) suggests this isn't a place that needs optimization. I know it's an itch to scratch, just suggesting it might actually not be that itchy.

Comment: I guess you're right, getting rid of garbage collection is a big enough win and extra checks shouldn't matter much since those functions are relatively heavyweight already. Emscripten has some variables called `UINT8` and such that hold relevant views, but I couldn't find a single place where they are assigned in the entire source (aside from tests).

Comment: They are assigned here?: https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/9a07fdfce7eabcf43fb341bf0c6741f3875544bc/src/preamble.js#L885